# Relationship between limits.conf and LDAP?

Tags: debian, ldap, limit

This seems like a straight forward question:

- Is there a relationship between the groups defined in ldap `ldif`
  files and `/etc/security/limits.conf` ?

### *I.e.,*

- does defining an LDAP
  user with `ou=student` translate to `@student` effects from
  `/etc/security/limits.conf`?
- If not, (how) can it be made to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groups defined with the `@group` syntax in the `limits.conf` file can match groups defined in any group database back-end, i.e. files (`/etc/group`), `nis`, `ldap`, and whatever else `nsswitch.conf` might support.

Assigning a group to an `ldap` user entry is not done by locating his/her entry somewhere in the hierarchy (like under `ou=student` in your question) but by defining group entries and populating them, i.e. adding them as secondary groups to users. That's not really different from what you would do with the local files (`/etc/passwd` & `/etc/group`), it's just where the information is stored and how it is done that changes.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't mean to be dense. So how would I assign LDAP users to the student group using LDAP (or Kerberos) mechanisms/files?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a clue about your Unix or Linux distribution, the directory server used, its DIT and the ldap server and client configurations.

Comment: Well, it's Debian using Kerberos with an LDAP backend. Is there no way to dish up group membership via LDAP either separate or together with login and generation of the user's home?

Comment: The generation of user's home directory is unrelated. There are certainly ways to have them created at first login but you should ask a different question to get details about it. An "ldap backend" is vague but in any case, whatever you can do with files, you can do with ldap so yes, as long as you have sufficient (admin) rights on the directory server, you can create users and groups there and assign the latter to the former.

Comment: The LDAP/Kerberos setup is remarkably similar to the one detailed here: http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-d6-kerberos-openldap-provider.php

Comment: For example, there is a user "George" who belongs to the group "noedit" when he logs on to any machine in the lab (using Kerberos + LDAP) he does not have permission to use Nano.
Or more in keeping with the question as originally articulated - as a member of the group "nowrite"  his nproc are limited to 20.